# What is wrong with this rails template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thor

I am attempting to take a whack at creating my first Rails application template and I am running into a slight issue with the `copy_file` method.

First some background.... Apparently the Ruby OpenSSL package does not ship with a CA store, so any attempt to connect to an HTTPS service will fail out of the box.  The way around this(for Rails 3 apps) is to add the line `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` to the top of your `config/environment.rb` file.  I need to do this on the fly in my template so I can install jQuery.

So I have that all figured out, my general thought is to:

1. Make a backup of my `config/environment.rb` file.
2. Prepend the data to original
3. Run the `jquery:install --ui` task
4. Restore the original `config/environment.rb` file.

See [my template Gist](https://gist.github.com/876122/), Lines 25..34 is the relevant section.

So all of that works until step #4 which fails with `Error: Could not find "env.orig" in any of your source paths` on line #31.
This is VERY perplexing to me because line #28 works, I can see the `env.orig` file on disk, so why won't the reverse work?

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update 1:

After looking at the Thor source `thor\actions.rb` it became clear that Thor uses different paths (not your current project path) for the source and destination. Furthermore my copy was actually *not* working, it was actually coping the ERB template file, not the already generated file.

After a breather it occurred to me *use the right tool for the job* so now I have: `run 'cp environment.rb environment.~'` and `run 'mv environment.~ environment.rb'` which works just fine.  I am fairly certain this would not work on a windows box without the unix tools installed, but I can live with that.  Does anyone have a *better* way?

Comment: wiseass answer: wait for Rails 3.1 or until Edge has jquery in it. It'll be default in 3.1 :)

Comment: what are the permissions on the new file?

Comment: @DGM... hard to tell as I am on Win32 and not a posix system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my Update for a Why, but the solution was to *use the right tool for the job* so now I have: `run 'cp environment.rb environment.~'` and `run 'mv environment.~ environment.rb'` which works just fine.  I am fairly certain this would not work on a windows box without the unix tools installed, but I can live with that.